# nginx redirect non www to www while maintainng protocol

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to redirect non www to www but making sure to keep the requested protocol so 80 would go to `http://www.` and 443 would go to `https://www.`

I have gotten this far..

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443;
server_name domain.com;
# add ssl settings
return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. separate http and https server config.
2. change `return 301 ...` to `rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 permanent;` (http or https)
3. change `listen 443;` to `listen 443 ssl;`

Comment: That works great however when I go to domain.com it adds // to the end so: `http://www.domain.com//`  https works fine, weird!